# Bind few columns to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, dataset

I have two tables in dataset

Cities and Countries.

I want to display in combobox city name plus country name.

My Tables appears to:

```
Cities:
int ID 
varchar(max) Name
varchar(2) CountryCode

Countries:
varchar(2) Code
varchar(max) Name
```

Now, my combobox appears to:

```
 dictionaryData1.Cities.DefaultView.Sort = dictionaryData1.Cities.NameColumn.ColumnName;
                cityLabeledComboBoxInput.DataSource = dictionaryData1.Cities;
                cityLabeledComboBoxInput.DisplayMember = dictionaryData1.Cities.NameColumn.ColumnName;
                cityLabeledComboBoxInput.ValueMember = dictionaryData1.Cities.CitiesIDColumn.ColumnName;
```

Is there any way to display name from those two tables?

Maybe adding another column in sql (sic!) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Format event of the ComboBox and find the parent row of the item and set the Value property of the event arg.

```
void comboBox_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
        DataRowView cityRow = e.ListItem as DataRowView;
        string city = cityRow["name"].ToString();
        DataRow countryRow = cityRow.Row.GetParentRow("parentRelation");
        string country = countryRow["name"].ToString();
        e.Value = city + " " + country;
}
```

Or you could add a column in the cities-table with the expression property set to the parent relation and display that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this as your data source, though this assumes a lot about your DAL.

```
select Countries.Code + '.' + cast(Cities.ID as varchar(15)) as ValueMember, 
       Cities.Name + ', ' + Countries.Name
from ...
    inner join ...
```

Comment: It generates me error  Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables . I think I must focus on combobox functionality :/

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to the following SQL as your data source for your dataset:

```
SELECT City.ID, City.Name + ", " + Country.Name AS CityCountry
FROM Cities City
   INNER JOIN Countries Country ON City.CountryID = Country.CountryID
```

Another option would be similar to the above, but would provide some additional reusability:  Create a view from the above SQL.

Comment: It generates me error  Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables . I think I must focus on combobox functionality :/

Comment: Then I would recommend creating a View using the SQL above.  You should be able to create a simple dataset (no matter how you're instantiating it) from that View.